# Across vs. Between

Tags: grammar

I'm writing about the use of mathematical methods for the investigation of scale-specific processes.

Which expression is more suitable:

- the study of interactions across scales
- the study of interactions between scales

The term "scales" refers to space and time scales.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean. I assume by scale you mean large and small, not apparatus for weighing. But is the interaction occurring between large and small, or at different sizes but between things of similar size?

Comment: Please provide a sentence that shows the context. **Between** is locative; **across** can be locative or express motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Interactions between" doesn't seem to work here.

That's because it always refers to the things that are interacting (e.g. "interactions between predators and prey") and, as far as I can tell, you're not saying that one scale interacts with another scale. If you are, you'll need to explain the concept. You seem to be saying that interactions between things involved in your processes take place on several scales. "Across" works for that.